# Using "UNSAFE_componentWillMount" in strict mode. But I'm not sure where the issue is

Tags: next.js

I have a *Next.js* application that when run, gives me this issue on the browsers console.

```
Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

* Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.

Please update the following components: SideEffect(NullComponent)
```

I am not sure what `SideEffect(NullComponent)` is and searching through all the text in my project returns no result. So I'm not sure where the problem is coming from in order to try and resolve it, or be able to provide some relevant code in here.

[image]

What does this error mean, and how can I locate at least what file is causing the issue?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the error log on your browser console?

Comment: @RyanLe I didn't initially do it since there doesn't seem to be any relevant information in there. At lest nothing that I can understand.

Comment: Q: Did you look at the documentation for this ReactJS component: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?  It mentions `This method is considered legacy and you should avoid it in new code:`.  It also says (related to your question) `Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in the constructor. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.`

Comment: I sort of got the hang on how to properly build next.js components, simple ones at least. In this particular case I have not written the problematic code I think. It must be an issue of some package that npm has downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The error that you see is most likely the be in a package that you are using**

Try to search for the whole project (including node_modules folder) or look more carefully in the console error (name of the file that generates the error).

This way you will know which package uses the outdated code and decide to keep it or update it or use another similar package.

---

To search for the whole project including node_modules

[image]